# Item combination with a limit number.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm new here. I'd like to ask a question.

I'd like to know if there's a fast way to count a number of combination of item that total is under or equal the limit.

Let's say:

- A = 5
- B = 3
- C = 7

Limit = 10

So, the combination should  be:

- A,A
- A,B
- B,B,B
- B,C
- C

The items and the limit may varies though.

Answer (score 1):

There's not going to be a simple closed-form expression for the answer.

We can use generating functions to get somewhere. In the example, the number of combinations would be the coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the series
$$f(x) = \frac1{1-x} \cdot \frac1{1-x^5} \cdot \frac1{1-x^3} \cdot \frac1{1-x^7}$$
and in general we would have a factor of $\frac1{1-x}$ followed by a factor of $\frac1{1-x^k}$ for each item of value $k$.

The reasoning here is that $\frac1{1-x^k}$ expands as $1 + x^k + x^{2k} + x^{3k} + \dots$. The item of value $k$ can appear $0, 1, 2, 3, \dots$ times, contributing $0, k, 2k, 3k, \dots$ to the total, and the power of $x$ reflects that. Multiplying the series for the different items together lets us combine them, and the $\frac1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + \dots$ factor acts as "padding": it allows us to go under the total rather than hitting it exactly.

Of course, extracting the coefficients from this series is difficult by hand (though a computer is fine differentiating a rational function as many times as you want, so then you get the Taylor series).

---

A different approach is to define: $A(n)$ to be the number of combinations using $A$ alone, $B(n)$ to be the number of combinations using $A$ and $B$, and $C(n)$ to be the number of combinations using all three (and so on for more items). Then the first function is simple to write down and each next function has a recursive definition in terms of the previous. In the example:

- $A(n) = \lfloor \frac n5 \rfloor+1$ since we can include any number of $A$'s from $0$ up to $\lfloor \frac n5\rfloor$.
- $B(n) = A(n) + A(n-3) + A(n-6) + \dots$ depending on how many $B$'s we include.
- $C(n) = B(n) + B(n-7) + B(n-14) + \dots$ depending on how many $C$'s we include.

For $n=10$, we'd get
\begin{align}
  C(10) &= B(10) + B(3) \\
        &= A(10) + A(7) + A(4) + A(1) + A(3) + A(0) \\
        &= \left\lfloor \frac{10}5\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{7}5\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{4}5\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{1}5\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{3}5\right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{0}5\right\rfloor + 6 \\
        &= 2 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 6 = 9
\end{align}
corresponding to: 
$$\varnothing,\; A,\; AA,\; B,\; AB,\; BB,\; BBB,\; C,\; BC$$
In a sense, this is nothing more than a systematic way of doing things by hand, but we may try to write down algebraic expressions for $B(n)$ and $C(n)$ using floor functions.